# Can you insert null value into date datatype in SQL (and if yes, how)?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, null

I have been working on my SQL database for school project and I have a problem with my idea. I am doing a car service database (all made up) and I have a column `deadline` of datatype `date` for a table `order` (names for both in my language - 'rok' and 'narocilo') and I am trying to insert null into some of rows where deadline isn't specified by the customer.

```
create table narocilo
(
    id_narocila integer NOT null,
    opis varchar(50),
    cena integer,
    status varchar(20),
    datum_narocila date,
    rok date
);
```

This is some ways i tried to insert null but none of them worked

- `to_date('dd-mm-yyyy', null)`
- `to_date(null)`
- `null`
- `to_date('null')`

So, my question is, can I insert null into a `date` column and if yes, how?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `null` by itself should have worked.

Comment: `null` is already default, if you do not provide a `non-null` value, it inserts a `null` implicitly. e.g. `insert into narocilo values(111);` inserts a `null` for `datum_narocila`

Comment: Works for me ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f79d8e/1)). Please show your `INSERT` statements and what exact problems you faced with them, e.g. error messages.

Answer (score 4):

You have to insert an entire row's worth of data, but as long as you have not defined that field as NOT NULL like you have above, it should be fine to insert NULL values into the date fields:

```
INSERT INTO narocilo(id_narocila, opis, cena, status, datm_narocila, rok)
VALUES (1001, 'something', 6, 'Open', NULL, NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to `insert` `NULL` is to leave them out of the `insert` altogether:

```
INSERT INTO narocilo (id_narocila, opis, cena, status)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);
```

Technically, this inserts the default value.  But you haven't specified one, so the default is `NULL`.